# OSX Shell Script to Read from list of Network Adapters?

Tags: bash, macos, networking, terminal, scripting

I have created a shell script to allow users to autoconfigure their network adapter.  Part of the script lists the network adapters currently connected, then reads the user input to type the listed adapter exactly as it appears.  It then applies the network name to make the IP changes.  I want to limit user error by having terminal list the adapters and the user only has to choose options 1-6 to complete the setup.

I tried to delimit the list using awk and having the script just default to the priority device but since many different adapters plugged in and there is no uniformity of machines made it difficult.

```
    IP_ADDR="192.168.1.22"
    SUBNET="255.255.255.0"
    D_GATE="192.168.1.1"
    DNS1="8.8.8.8"
    DNS2="8.8.4.4"

    # Find your adapter
    echo I am going to show you a list of adapters. Find the correct one and write down the Service name.
    # List adapters
    networksetup -listallnetworkservices

    # Asking them to find it
    echo What is the the Service name of the adapter you are going to use?

    # Get the users input
    read NIC_SERVICE

    # Restate NIC that was typed
    echo you typed $NIC_SERVICE If that is incorrect IP Address will not saved
    sleep 2s
    clear

    # Set Ip Address
    if [ 192.168.1.22 != "" ] && [ "$NIC_SERVICE" != "" ]
    then
    networksetup -setmanual "$NIC_SERVICE" 192.168.1.22 255.255.255.0 192.168.1.1
    networksetup -setdnsservers "$NIC_SERVICE" 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
    fi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to use the built in select command? Here a simple example

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS="
"

select V in $(networksetup -listallnetworkservices);do
    echo "DO WHATEVER WITH $V"
done
```

Comment: I have not!   And forgive me because im trying my best to learn and piece things together as i can to make it work.   Ill try it out and report back.

Comment: Nothing to forgive, I also learned that from a stackoverflow user :)

Comment: This worked perfectly.  I had to kill the echo portion otherwise it would loop indefinately. 

Would you mind giving me an explaination?   I know it works but i dont necessarily understand why or how.

The select command is exactly what i was looking for.  But i dont understand why if ran without IFS it gives an option to select every word, but when used with IFS it gives each adapter.

Also, the done statement at the end.   Why does that need to be in the script?  Seems i have to put it at the end of the entire script rather than just the end of this section that calls for IFS.

Comment: IFS is a special bash variable (Input Field Separator) which defines what character act as field separator. If you want your output to be divided line by line (as in your case), IFS must be defined with newline value (as in my code snippet).
The done keyword is part of the select statement, that require the iterated code to be between do and done (like in FOR and WHILE loops). If this helped you, consider to vote my answer ;)